# SQL setting a sub querys where value from the main query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime, subquery

Looking to get the where statement value in my sub query values from the main query.

This is a cut down version of what im trying to achieve but it will give you the idea.

```
SELECT  Date, Day, Year, 

(SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Moves]
FROM 
    (
    SELECT moves AS too
    FROM moveevent
    FULL OUTER JOIN job AS too ON moves = too.jobid
    WHERE  (moveevent.time >= [start] and moveevent.time <= [end])
UNION ALL
    SELECT moves AS frm
    FROM moveevent
    FULL OUTER JOIN job AS frm ON moves = frm.jobid
    WHERE  (moveevent.time >= [start] and moveevent.time <= [end])
    )   
    AS m
FULL OUTER JOIN job ON m.too = jobid
WHERE mainjobid = jobid
GROUP BY jobid) 
) 
      AS [Total Moves by Shift],


FROM    job
LEFT OUTER JOIN mainjob ON jobid = mainjobid

WHERE jobid = '12345' 
and [start] = '2013-05-25 12:45:00.000'
and [end] = '2013-05-25 17:45:00.000'
```

Basically i want the start and end values in the sub query to be defined by the main query but i cannot get them to be valid column names.

**The names "start" and "end", these are not fields in any table these are just made up, i want to be able to set these in the main queries where clause at the bottom.**

Comment: Why are you using the exact same query in the `UNION ALL`? Or is it a typo?

Comment: Do you know Common Table Expressions (CTE)? I don't know if I understand the issue correctly but it could help you in this case.

Comment: The union is to bring together too and frm moves, this is just a cut down version but it is needed for other parts to differentiate between the two.

Comment: @Matt but you only return the `COUNT(*)` from the subquery, so there won't be anything to differentiate later on..

Comment: @NickyvV ignore the main code, the majority of the code isnt the issue here its defining start and end in the sub query then giving them values in the main query

Comment: Can't you use parameters then? Is it a Stored Procedure e.g.? You're saying `mysql` and `sql-server`, which is it?

Comment: the names "start" and "end" are not fields in any table these are just made up, i then want to be able to set these in the main queries where clause at the bottom.

Probably should have mentioned this in the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME
SET @start = '2013-05-25 12:45:00.000'
SET @end = '2013-05-25 17:45:00.000'
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Moves]
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT moves AS too
        FROM moveevent
        FULL OUTER JOIN job AS too ON moves = too.jobid
        WHERE  (moveevent.time >= @start and moveevent.time <= @end)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT moves AS frm
        FROM moveevent
        FULL OUTER JOIN job AS frm ON moves = frm.jobid
        WHERE  (moveevent.time >= @start and moveevent.time <= @end)
        )   
        AS m
```

I tested it shortly but not definitily. Please give me a feedback.

Comment: Hello, my code is a cut down version of it, the bulk of the code isnt the issue here its defining start and end in the sub query then giving them values in the main query

Comment: Ohh, sorry now I unterstand what do you want. let me think about it

Comment: Yeh so in the sub query i use the names "start" and "end", these are not fields in any table these are just made up, i then want to be able to set these in the main queries where clause at the bottom.

Comment: Worked perfect using the declare and set! Was thinking of this but couldnt quite get it working! Thanks Guys!